# Jquery remove br tag on above

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a dynamic field that can add and can remove.

But in my script, the remove button is removing input field and all br lines.

I want it to only remove what i click

```
var max_fields      = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<br>');
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="meaning[]" class="form-control" /><a href="#" class="remove_field"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" id="trash"></span></a></div>'); //add input box

        }

    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
         $("br").remove();
    })
```

The above code removes all br when i click remove.

What can i do if i want to remove only parent div?

Comment: how can i conbine br in $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="meaning[]" class="form-control" /><a href="#" class="remove_field"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" id="trash"></span></a></div>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `prev()` function:

```
// Store $(this) to a variable in order not to call jQuery multiple times
var that = $(this);
that.parent('div').remove(); x--;
that.prev('br').remove();
```

Check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: A better way would be to use siblings if you can. Prev can be dangerous in some situations, for eg, your HTML structure changed then are you going to reqrite your selectors.